# Ways to use raco to sacrifice compile time for performance?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compiler-construction, racket, nasm

I had a project for my university, where I had to improve the compiler that we had written throughout the course in Racket. I was recently reading about GCC -O optimizations, and -O3 and -Ofast were able to significantly speed up my runtime program, which is written in C. Is there some sort of quick way I could boost performance at the cost of compile-time? My class only cared about program runtime, but the testing used I/O so I couldn't have the compiler run the program and just compile the answer. We are using raco to compile the compiler, so I was wondering if there are any raco or even NASM options or optimizations I could have used? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. There is no flag you can give `raco` to get it to optimize your code. (At least not at the time of writing this answer.)

However, if you use [Pycket](https://github.com/pycket/pycket) (a Racket compiler & runtime written with pypy), your code may run faster.  If memory serves, Pycket is not 100% compatible with Racket, but does a pretty good job for everything but the most complex programs.

Comment: One thing that might be worth mentioning is that Racket performs a lot of optimizations already. So the issue here is simply that it's currently not possible to control optimization levels. It is not the case that Racket compiler is inefficient or anything like that.